# UISegmentController with UITableviewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a table view which has a segment controller and it has two segments category 1 and 2 respectively. When I add an item to category 1 it perfectly done but when I am adding an item to category 2 it crashes the app saying that 'Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'.
Here its my code for insertion into table view.

For category 1:

```
func itemDetailViewController(controller: ItemDetailViewController, didFinishAddingItem item: NoToDoItem) {
    let newRowIndex = items.count

    items.append(item)

    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: newRowIndex, inSection: 0)
    let indexPaths = [indexPath]
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

and for category 2:

```
func itemDetailViewController(controller: ItemDetailViewController, didFinishAddingNotSureItem notSureItem: NotSureItem) {
    let newRowIndex = notSureItems.count

    notSureItems.append(notSureItem)

    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: newRowIndex, inSection: 0)
    let indexPaths = [indexPath]
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: And what about the other code where you create the instances and use them to populate the table view(s)

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12874960/.  Here its my other code @Wain

Comment: Seems like you are not populating the dataSource array for the second category table, Did you debug with break points in delegate methods?

Comment: Try using beginUpdates() and endUpdates() for inserting new row. everything else seems fine.

Comment: Its giving me a same crash after adding beginUpdates and endUpdates @BhaumikDesai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your table shows the same category you currently add to? Try this:

```
func itemDetailViewController(controller: ItemDetailViewController, didFinishAddingItem item: NoToDoItem) {
    let newRowIndex = items.count

    items.append(item)
    if segmentBar.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: newRowIndex, inSection: 0)
        let indexPaths = [indexPath]
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    }
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

and do the same for `didFinishAddingNotSureItem`.

Also ensure that you reload your tableview when changing the category.

Comment: when I select category 1 its adding an item but when I select category 2 its does not appears in segment index 1 @replman

Comment: Add a breakpoint in didFinishAddingItem and didFinishAddingNotSureItem. Then insert an item in category 2. When the debugger stopps, be sure to be in the main thread. Then type "po segmentBar.selectedSegmentIndex" into the console and verify that it returns category 2.

Comment: When you change to category 2, do you call tableView.reloadData()?

Comment: What do you mean with 'its not visible'? Does the notSureItems array contain entries but the tableview stays empty in category 2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92830/discussion-between-shahin-ali-agharia-and-replman).

Answer (score 0):

UITableView must be kept in sync with the data source at all times. Special care must be taken if the data source can change in a background thread.

When something is added to the data source, call beginUpdate/insert/endUpdate as soon as possible. So try this:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()

let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: newRowIndex, inSection: 0)
let indexPaths = [indexPath]
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

tableView.endUpdates()
```

PS: Trusting your datasource model object `notSureItems` is set correctly and that `numberOfRowsInSection` function returns the correct count.

**EDIT :** Post OP comments

You are trying to add row at wrong index. Table view indexes starts with 0 so this is how you should deduce your new cell index:

```
notSureItems.append(notSureItem)
let newRowIndex = notSureItems.count - 1
```

Also, put a break point in your `itemDetailViewController` and `numberOfRowsInSection` functions to check the model values.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).' Now it shows this crash @Abhinav

Comment: For your information I had created a alert controller which has action category 1 and 2 respectively. When i select one of those category it should be inside that segment which I had created. The above edited answer is also giving me the same crash again.

Comment: What does that mean. I am stumped!

Comment: As I said earlier, I suspect, your table view is not in sync with data model. You need to put break point and check data model state before inserting a new row. You can move model update statement in `beginUpdate` `endUpdate` block.

Comment: Look I have add button on main table view controller with segmented controller segment control has 2 parts category one and two. When I click on add button it push me to next view and then i clicked on done button for adding an item to table view. It pop up an alert in which category you have save. Thats It

Comment: This is a useful information. Please put it in your question for others in community to brainstorm in right direction. Also, no harm being polite especially when asking for help :)!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92816/discussion-between-shahin-ali-agharia-and-abhinav).